# A CUDA kernel for a matrix product as outer product vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda

To multiply the matrices A and B using the outer product of vectors, we can express each row of matrix A as a row vector and each column of matrix B as a column vector. Then, we can take the outer product of each row vector of A with each column vector of B and sum the results.

The outer product of two vectors u and v is the matrix uv^T, where u is a column vector and v^T is a row vector. The product of A and B can be expressed as:

AB = sum_i sum_j A_i * B_j^T

where A_i and B_j^T are the ith row of A and jth column of B, respectively.

Using this formula, we can calculate AB as follows:

```
AB = [[1 2 3]   [[1 4 7]
      [4 5 6] *  [2 5 8]
      [7 8 9]]   [3 6 9]]

   = [[1*1+2*4+3*7 1*2+2*5+3*8 1*3+2*6+3*9]
      [4*1+5*2+6*3 4*2+5*5+6*8 4*3+5*6+6*9]
      [7*1+8*2+9*3 7*2+8*5+9*8 7*3+8*6+9*9]]

   = [[30   36  42]
      [34   65  96]
      [102 126 150]]
```

Therefore, the product of A and B using the outer product of vectors is:

```
AB = [[30 36 42]
      [66 81 96]
      [102 126 150]]
```

---

I implemented the above as a CUDA kernel.

In this version, each block of K threads will compute a square piece of the result matrix of size KxK by implementing the matrix outer product formula.

To do this, I used shared memory to store the corresponding column vectors from matrix A and matrix B and to store the corresponding fragment of the result array.

Can you review the following source code for a CUDA kernel?

```
__global__ void matrixOuterProductKernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int K) {
    // Calculate the row and column indices of the current thread
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    // Allocate shared memory for storing the relevant vectors and result fragment
    __shared__ float sA[K][K];
    __shared__ float sB[K][K];
    __shared__ float sC[K][K];
    
    // Initialize the result fragment to zero
    sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = 0.0;
    
    // Loop over the necessary vectors and accumulate the result fragment
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        // Load the relevant elements of the vectors into shared memory
        sA[threadIdx.y][i] = A[row * K + i];
        sB[i][threadIdx.x] = B[i * K + col];
        
        // Wait for all threads to finish loading the vectors
        __syncthreads();
        
        // Calculate the outer product and add it to the result fragment
        for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
            sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] += sA[threadIdx.y][j] * sB[j][threadIdx.x];
        }
        
        // Wait for all threads to finish the current iteration before loading the next vectors
        __syncthreads();
    }
    
    // Write the result fragment back to global memory
    C[row * K + col] = sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outer product vectors"?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike, Corrected.

Comment: No, not corrected. What is the "matrix outer product formula"? Even if you had written "vector outer product", I would still expect at least a link to an explanation of what that means. I don't know what a "matrix outer product" is.